# How do I get sqlalchemy.create_engine with mysqlconnector to connect using mysql_native_password?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-connector-python

I'm working with pandas and sqlalchemy, and would like to load a DataFrame into a MySQL database. I'm currently using this code snippet:

```
db_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pwd@hostname/db_name')

some_data_ref.to_sql(con=db_connection, name='db_table_name', if_exists='replace')
```

`sqlalchemy`, `pandas` have been imported prior to this.

My MySQL backend is 8.x, which I know uses `caching_sha2_password`. If I were to connect to the database using `mysql.connector.connect` and I want to use the `mysql_native_password` method, I know that I should specify `auth_plugin = mysql_native_password` like so:

```
mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=pw, host=host, database=db, auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
```

My question: Is there a way to force `mysql_native_password` authentication with `sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://...)`?

Any advice on this would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`connect_args`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.connect_args):

```
db_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    'mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pwd@hostname/db_name',
    connect_args={'auth_plugin': 'mysql_native_password'})
```

or the URL [query](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.params.query):

```
db_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    'mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pwd@hostname/db_name?auth_plugin=mysql_native_password')
```

Comment: Any idea why I'd get an `got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth_plugin'` error when following these instructions?

Comment: Newer version of mysqlconnector or different driver altogether?

Comment: What made this answer work for me with mysql 5.7 was to drop pymsql and then pip3 install mysqlclient